# Setting image height to container height and keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way, using solely CSS, to set an image's height to its container's height, while maintaining aspect ratio, allowing the width to overflow and be hidden? That sounds like a lot of requirements, but surely there's a way. What I mean is, I want the full height of the image to be displayed, but if the width is wider than the container allows (using bootstraps grid system), then just overflow: hidden. I have the height set to 100% which looks good, but the picture squishes in from the sides to fit inside the container rather than overflowing and being cropped. By setting width to 100%, it's filling the container. I believe it's using the container as the standard for the 100%, rather than the aspect ratio of the photo. So that's what I need to do.

This is what I have going on:

```html
<div style="width:150px; height:150px; display:flex; flex-direction:column">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RiX7XfW.jpg" alt="Banana" style="height:100%;width:auto;overflow:hidden">
</div>
```

TL;DR I need to maintain aspect ration of an image, lock the height to the container height and let the excess of the picture just overflow and be hidden, allowing me to see the maximum amount of the picture possible, while still filling the container.

Bonus points if there's a way to somehow calculate which dimension is smaller and lock that one to the relevant container dimension.

Comment: Just set the image as the container's `background-image` and then use `background-size:cover;` and `background-position:center center;`

Comment: Beautiful! Make this an answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @APAD1 make this an answer, and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of embedding the image with an `img` tag, you can set the image as the background image of the container. Then by using a combination of `background-size:cover;` and `background-position:center center;` you can cause the image to match the height of the container while keeping the aspect ratio of the original image. The `background-position` property will center the image so that the left and right sides are cropped off.

Using shorthand, that code would look like this:

```html
<div style="background:url('http://i.imgur.com/RiX7XfW.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat; width:150px; height:150px; display:flex; flex-direction:column"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to do this if using an image tag, but if using the CSS background-image property (or the shortcut `background`), then

```css
#wrap{width:300px;height:200px;margin:50px;overflow:hidden;}
  #imgDiv{width:1000px;height:1000px;background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/900/900); background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="imgDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Running this snippet, I only see a small portion of the picture. I need to see as much of the photo as possible, locking one of the dimensions to its container. Perhaps your solution has a browser-specific incompatibility?

Answer (score 0):

Are you suggesting `overflow: hidden` in the CSS? It's a routine default measure, and you speak around it, like you might be recalling the measure.

Not setting a height, and setting `width: 100%`, is a nice way to regard the aspect ratio with more concern to the full width. So `height: 100%` without a specification for width may be a best way to keep full height with aspect ratio intact.